# I always have to login to google again?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-account

Everytime my battery ends, and the phone turns off, I'll have to login to google again? Isn't there a way to keep my login information even if the mobile restarts?

By the way, I use double check login, but after the first confirmation with the sms code, it should not ask for the login again.

Comment: This is not normal behavior. Please add some information about your device and how you are logging in to Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stopped to ask my password after about 4 reboots, or 4 days. I don't know what was causing the problem.